# Assign symbology for zipped shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology

I have some shapefiles that I am zipping up for another user and I would like for them to appear in the same symbology that I have used. Is there a way to create some sort of layer style aux file in QGIS that would automatically assign that symbology?

Comment: You can save layer symbology in Layer Properties > Style > Save Style. Then load it with Layer Properties > Style > Load Style. But if you're sending from one QGIS user to another, surely there is a better format for the geometry itself than to send shapefiles?

Answer (score 4):

QGIS has *.qml files that can go together with shapefiles storing the symbology.

To do it quickly:

- Right click on the QGIS layer > Properties
- Go to "Style" tab
- Click the "Style" button at the bottom of the window
- Click "set as default".

A *.qml file should have been created together with the files of your shapefile, and the style will be preserved whenever you open the shapefile in QGIS again.

Comment: I didn't know that. Very helpful. Thank you.